# What does it mean to bootstrap a classifier?

Tags: classification, data-mining, bootstrap

I'm reading a paper on data mining, and the authors mentioned that "we bootstrapped a classifier". I understand that bootstrapping means sampling with replacement, but I didn't understand how that relates to classifiers.

Comment: Can you supply a reference to said paper? I can't conceive of any situation in which one would "bootstrap a classifier".

Answer (score 1):

This probably refers to training a set of classifiers on bootstrap samples of the training set. In case the classifier is an ensemble model (such as random forests), it likely refers to a bagging approach. In any case it is a pretty poor choice of words.

Comment: "The classifier is an ensemble model (such as random forests), it likely refers to a bagging approach". I'm not following your explanation here. How are they bootstrapping *the model* exactly? Or are they simulating data from this prediction model in some way?

Comment: (too long for a good comment => answer)

Comment: @AdamO I can't speak for the specific paper the OP refers to without seeing it. Based on papers I have read in the past, ensemble models are sometimes said to "*bootstrap the base models*" to signify a bagging approach. I encountered several authors saying something along the lines of "we bootstrapped 500 decision trees into a random forest". This is a poor way of denoting a bagging approach but it occurs. Bootstrapping a model, to my knowledge, is always a poor choice of words to say that a set of models were trained on bootstrap resamples of the training set.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is also that a number of classifiers is  built using bootstrap-resampled training data.

I don't think it needs to be a bagged classifier, though (as that would usually be called, well, bagged classifier): I often train lots of surrogate models on resampled training data and then check the stability of the model parameters and/or of predictions made by the models.

I don't bag the classifier if the predictions are reasonably stable, though. But I still like to show that the classifier is stable wrt. slight changes in the training data.